# Jquery datatables - button to change value

Tags: jquery, mysql, button, datatables

I have a problem with change my datatable into server-side processing. My problem is getting value of td in the same tr as button. I tried to get it by:

```
$(".zapl").live('click', function() {
    var parent = $(this).parents('tr'); 
    var netto = $('.vat', parent).text();
}
```

But it not working. I want to do it like here: http://mojetesty.cba.pl/demo2.php . But I don't know how. Here is demo of my problem: http://mojetesty.cba.pl/demoo.php

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated.  Use `.on()` instead.

Comment: I cannot see any element with class vat inside your table <tr>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no element with the 'vat' class in your table, which is why your code is not working.

You have two choices:

(1) Use the [`sClass` property of DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/ref#sClass) to add the 'vat' class to the appropriate column.

(2) If the vat column is always going to be the fourth column, use:

```
var netto = $('td', parent).eq(3).text();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In "normal mode" I clone tr's with all class, and I don't remember to add them here.